# Matlab: Histogram dips after nomalization?

Tags: matlab, histogram, normalization

So I'm trying to replicate this histogram figure:
[image: expected result]

but I ended up with this histogram which dips in green and blue:
[image: failed result]

```
clear all;
close all;
clc;
% read and convert image into double
palm = imread('palm down.jpg');
doublePalm = im2double(palm);

%split into RGB
redPalm = doublePalm(:,:,1);
greenPalm = doublePalm(:,:,2);
bluePalm = doublePalm(:,:,3);

%normalize count
redPalm = (redPalm-min(redPalm(:)))/(max(redPalm(:))-min(redPalm(:)));
[yRed, xRed] = imhist(redPalm);

greenPalm = (greenPalm-min(greenPalm(:)))/(max(greenPalm(:))-min(greenPalm(:)));
[yGreen, xGreen] = imhist(greenPalm);

bluePalm = (bluePalm-min(bluePalm(:)))/(max(bluePalm(:))-min(bluePalm(:)));
[yBlue, xBlue] = imhist(bluePalm);

%mean
meanRed = mean2(redPalm);

figure;
subplot(1,2,1); plot(xRed, yRed, 'Red', xGreen, yGreen, 'Green', xBlue, yBlue, 'Blue'); title('RGB Channel'); xlabel('Intensity'); ylabel('Normalised Count');
```

*edit*
[palm down.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBJHC.jpg)

Comment: could you add the picture please? I am quite sure its a rounding issue that comes from your normalize calculation, but would have to check to be sure. Have you tried to do the `imhist` first and then make the normalize on `xRed`

Comment: Thanks @Miraj50 for the formatting help. I switched the imhist and normalization calculation and it worked! Thank you for the help!